# Is there a way to actually append the current timestamp onto this json file?

Tags: java, json, file-io

public static String FILE_LOCATION = "/fitness"+File.separator
+"customers_" + "yyyymmddmmss" + ".json";

this is what i have so far.

Comment: You want rename file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format `String` includes `mm` twice and no `HH` for hours. But yes, using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and something like

```
public static String FILE_LOCATION = "/fitness/customers_"
            + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            .format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ".json";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the local date-time (which is different in different time-zones) to be captured as part of the name of the file, the [answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546222/10819573) is what you need.

However, if you want the date-time to be independent of a time-zone, you can append the value of `Instant.now()` which gives you current moment at UTC time-line.

```
public static String FILE_LOCATION = "/fitness/customers_"
            + Instant.now().toString() + ".json";
```

or in the custom format as

```
public static String FILE_LOCATION = "/fitness/customers_"
            + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            .format(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)) + ".json";
```

Note that `LocalDateTime.now()` is equivalent to `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` which gives you the date-time in the JVM's time-zone.

Comment: It worked for one of my classes but the other one is giving me an exception. Do you know how I'd be able to fix this?                                                                                           
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 38